# Get all the GoogleForm responses on Today's timestamp

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, array-formulas, google-sheets-query, gs-vlookup

I have a GoogleForm - whose submission are saved on a google sheet as below

[image]

The GoogleForm is a Log entry of how person feels the submission is done daily, and we need a separate sheet that gives all the Form responses on the timestamp that were done today.

The below sheet is the final report, for all the entries that were done today. We have the list of members saved on another sheet and members who have not made a entry must also be listed.

[image]

Google Sheet Example :
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Rykh6hveF2jPltTkWXlXWJ_UNJIgNdyAqCK9CZNsqQY/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(QUERY({'Form Responses'!A2:B, 
 IFNA(VLOOKUP('Form Responses'!C2:C, Members!A2:B, 2, 0))}, 
 "select Col3,Col1,Col2 
  where Col1 = date '"&TEXT(TODAY(), "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'", 0), "no data"))
```

[image: 0]